# Running Airflow in Docker \ chown: changing ownership of '/sources/{logs,dags,plugins}': Invalid argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, ubuntu-20.04, chown

When I try to start the Airflow services with `docker compose --profile flower up`, the following errors occur when starting the airflow-airflow-init-1 container:

> chown: changing ownership of '/sources/logs': Invalid argument
> chown: changing ownership of '/sources/dags': Invalid argument
> chown: changing ownership of '/sources/plugins': Invalid argument
> The container is run as root user. For security, consider using a regular user account.

What else should I do in order for the three chowns to work (so that the files created in dags, logs and plugins be created with root user ownership)?

I followed every step in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html to run Airflow in Docker on an Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS host, including the following two commands ("Setting the right Airflow user"):

```
mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins ./config
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env
```

I confirm that there is an .env file with the following variable in the folder containing docker-compose.yaml:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=<uid>
```

And that  equals the Uid in the result of `stat {logs,dags,plugins}`.

I expected the setting of the AIRFLOW_UID envirnoment variable to be enough for the `chown`s to be able to succeed, but every one of them threw an 'Invalid argument' excepction.

The filesystem on the host is ext4 and the ones in the container, per `df -T`, are overlay for / and virtiofs for /opt/airflow/logs.

Comment: Generally, that's an error message that comes back from the kernel, which gets it from the filesystem layer. What's the filesystem in use? If it's something that doesn't support UNIX file ownership at all, well, there you are.

Comment: BTW, completely unrelated to your problem, the `-e` argument in `echo -e` is best avoided; [the POSIX spec for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) itself recommends using `printf` instead when you need backslash escapes... but in the example you give you aren't using backslash-escape sequences at all in the first place! Also see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se], which notes that in some modes bash's `echo -e` prints the string `-e` on output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for your comment and recommendation. As for the filesystems in use, the one on the host is ext4 and the ones in the container, per `df -T`, are overlay for / and virtiofs for /opt/airflow/logs.

Comment: ext4 itself definitely won't have a problem. overlayfs depends on what the layers under it are; I think that's also true of virtiofs and you'd need to look at the file system on the host being used to back it (and any config parameters; if the VM doesn't have enough privileges to pass through ownership changes to the host, there you are)